# In vim, how does one apply autocommands for a filetype to a region of a file?

Tags: vim, autocommand

I've got a kind of polyglot filetype that can have embedded C, python, ruby, etc in it (think 'wiki page' if it helps). Is there a way to execute the autocommands for a known filetype on a region of the file?

For example, I might have:

```
#!bash
if [ a = b ]; then
   echo 'equal'
fi

#!python
if a = b:
    print('equal')
```

And I want to apply bash filetype autocommands to the first part and python filetype autocommands to the latter part.

I can get just syntax hilighting by defining a region using [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file) method, but I don't understand autocommands enough to be able to apply them in a similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this automatically is challenging, as the filetype settings are buffer-local; Vim has no notion of regions, so `:autocmds` need to be used, as you've correctly stated.

#### Quick and easy

With a plugin like [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin similar to Emacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075), you can clone regions to separate scratch buffers; the plugin automatically syncs them back on write. Each buffer can be given a separate filetype via `:setf`.

An even simpler approach is to define some mappings to quickly switch filetypes:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>fp :setf python<CR>
:nnoremap <Leader>fs :setf sh<CR>
```

#### Really separate regions in a single buffer

The sketch of this is easy:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI <buffer> if line('.') >= 6 | setf python | else | setf sh | endif
```

This relies on each filetype plugin doing proper cleanup (or overriding all relevant options).

#### How to determine the regions

You certainly don't want to specify the line numbers explicitly as in the sketch above. My [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) might help, in case you have / can define proper syntax regions for each block.